# mongoose findbyidandupdate just passed values

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I would like to update only the values of an object that are passed.

```
            Event.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, {
            $set: {
                name: req.body.name,
                narrative: req.body.narrative,
                startdate: req.body.startdate,
                enddate: req.body.enddate,
                site: req.body.site
            }
            }, {new: true},
            function(err, Event) {
                if (err) throw err;

                res.send(Event);
            });
```

My function right now will null any fields not defined in the the post request.
For example if my object has all fields defined and I try to update just the name with:

```
{
    "id": "57b8fa4752835d8c373ca42d",
    "name": "test"
}
```

will result in:

```
{
 "_id": "57b8fa4752835d8c373ca42d",
 "name": "test",
 "narrative": null,
 "startdate": null,
 "enddate": null,
 "site": null,
 "__v": 0,
 "lastupdated": "2016-08-21T00:48:07.428Z",
 "sponsors": [],
 "attendees": []
}
```

Is there any way to perform this update with out having to pass all the other fields too?

Comment: are you sure, you have all the value in your `req.body`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason they are set to `null` when you don't send in all parameters is because your including `null` values in your updates.

The only way to prevent this is to check and ensure that your variables are set before you make the modification.

Something like:

```
var modifications = {};

// Check which parameters are set and add to object.
// Indexes set to 'undefined' won't be included.
modifications.name = req.body.name ?
  req.body.name: undefined; 

modifications.narrative = req.body.narrative ?
  req.body.narrative: undefined; 

modifications.startdate = req.body.startdate ?
  req.body.startdate: undefined; 

modifications.enddate = req.body.enddate ?
  req.body.enddate: undefined; 

modifications.site = req.body.site ?
  req.body.site: undefined; 


Event.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.body.id,
  {$set: modifications},
  {new: true},
  function(err, Event) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.send(Event);
});
```